# Initiate TCP connection from a browser (extension)?

Tags: browser, tcp, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is it possible to initiate a TCP connection from a browser?

If so, does there already exist browser (esp. Firefox and Chrome) extensions that do this? If no extensions exist yet, do you know the core elements/functions to create a Firefox/Chrome browser-initiated TCP connection?

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome Browser (I think since v24 in the stable channel) lets you host a TCP server, and the samples indicate that it can connect to a telnet server, which means that it is also capable of being a TCP client.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/tcpserver

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/telnet

But these are not standardized, so, if you can work with websockets, do prefer that.

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html

Answer (score 0):

There are Websockets, but they are limited to the websocket protocol outlined at [in RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

So far, most modern webbrowsers [support it](http://caniuse.com/websockets)