# Make arbitrary TCP connection from browser

Tags: javascript, web-applications

My web application needs to connect to a local device on the network to get data.

The device has a static IP address and communicates via the P03 protocol.  When I connect with Telnet, the device returns a plain text in my console.

I need to do the same thing with JavaScript in-browser.  When a user clicks a button, it should connect to `192.168.0.1:8000` via TCP and display the received text data on the page.

The problem is that is a web application.  Is it possible to do client-side?

(I'm also willing to accept other suggestions besides JavaScript.)

Comment: "Consult" is not a standard technical term. What do you mean.

Comment: "fill in a field" - what sort of field?

Comment: Are you asking how to make an HTTP post request?

Comment: I edited the post explaining myself better

Comment: Whatever this P03 protocol is, if it's not HTTP based then you could have a very hard time trying to handle it from Javascript. On the other hand, if it's a regular HTTP request, then `XmlHttpRequest` is all you need.

Comment: @deceze This was a salvageable question.  The relevant details were there, we just have a minor language barrier issue.  I wish you had not closed this question.

Comment: @Brad Well, *now* it's salvaged and reopened.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for re-opening.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot connect to just any TCP socket.  The browser can make connections, but it has to be one of these protocols:

- HTTP (HTTP[S] 1.0/1.1/2)
- Web Socket (another application protocol actually running on top of HTTP)
- WebRTC (intended for peer-to-peer, can be used for client-server communication as well, but not useful here)

One way to do this is to run a proxy of sorts.  You need to make a proxy that accepts Web Socket connections from browsers, and then relays the sent/received data to this TCP server.  The downside is that this requires a server.

Another way is to make a browser extension.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17567373/362536

Comment: @user1283776 I rolled back your edit... I don't want to add confusion here, implying that somehow Web Sockets can be disconnected from the HTTP context.

Comment: @Nick That's the case with anything over HTTP/1.x... you make a request, you get a response, and then the response body is often just sent as-is unless transfer encoding comes into play, so there really is no distinction.  For HTTP/2, that Web Socket connection does actually get encapsulated into an HTTP/2 stream, so yes Web Socket does run on top of HTTP.